# Import between Multiple VS 2022 Python solution projects

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, import, python-import, visual-studio-2022

I am struggling with imports in multiple python projects created in Visual Studio 2022.

I have 2 projects under the same solution as shown below.
[py project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cc1T.png)

The folder structure looks like -

```
Solution1
|--Project1
     |--a1.py
 |--Project2
     |--a2.py
```

All projects are on Python 3.8.
VS Version 17.3.4
Pylance - Python with Pylance 17.0.22179.3

I want to import a method (method1) from a1.py into a2.py. I have tried
`from Project1 import a1 as a1 import method1 from a1` 
and also

`from Project1.a1 import method1`

but I get the missing imports error.
I'd like to import from a1 into a2 to avoid duplication of variables and methods across different projects.

I have added Project1 as a reference in Project2 References and Search Paths but that still shows the error.

Here is the project properties for both -

[project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rDnC.png)

Answer (score 0):

The usual was is to have modules in the same folder or the child folders.

What you have here are essentially different projects, so you would probably need to go down the rout of absolute paths.

You can do this with the `sys` module like this:

```py
import sys

# Construct the absolute path to the module
module_path = "/path/to/my_module.py"

# Import the module
import module_path
```

You could also try relative paths like this:

```
# Import the module in the parent directory
from .. import my_module
```

Finally, you could use the `importlib` module which works like this:

```
import importlib

# Construct the absolute path to the module
module_path = "/path/to/my_module.py"

# Import the module
module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
```

However, it looks very similar to the `sys`module method.

**In summary**:

if i was ever going to do this, i would probably prefer the `sys` module method with an `absolute` path.

Comment: thanks for the suggest. Tried both the absolute path methods but it doesn't seem to work.
The `import module_path` method fails again due to being an unindentified module.
And the importlib method seems to crash my debugger and fail to import anyway. 
@d-l have you faced these obstacles as well?

Comment: @aidee:   i have never used the `importlib` module as the `import sys` has always worked for me without issue.  Perhaps it is the pathname....  what error are you getting ?    (i use `python 3.10` on `windows 11` or `windows 10`).

Comment: @d-l the error was from Pylance not recognizing the module name but on running the code, it is importing correctly. thanks for the help!